# How to describe an abandoned sailboat having been finally brought by winds to the shore?

Tags: word-choice

What's the verb to describe an abandoned sailboat being finally brought by the winds to the shore of a sea or of the ocean?

> The sailboat was finally brought to a shore. ?
>
> The sailboat was finally carried to a shore. ?
>
> The sailboat was finally borne to a shore. ?

Or what?

Comment: It's also more idiomatic to drop the indefinite article and just say *to shore*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the expression ***blown or [washed ashore](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wash%20ashore)***

> - to bring (something) onto the shore by waves *A lot of debris was washed ashore during the storm.* (M-W)

From [The Guardian](https://www.theguardian.com/uk-news/2016/aug/09/salvage-crew-board-oil-rig-transocean-winner-blown-ashore-lewis)

> Salvage crew plans to board oil rig blown ashore on Isle of Lewis

Answer (score 3):

You could say drifted. Which means:

- be carried slowly by a current of air or water.
  "the cabin cruiser started to drift downstream"
  synonyms:   be carried, be borne; More

As in:

The sailboat finally drifted to shore.

‘Drifted’ means that the sailboat was not moving under its own power, but rather that it was out of control; being propelled by the wind or waves.

Answer (score 0):

The term for an object either deliberately or accidentally are brought ashore is [beached](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/beached):

> Hauled up or stranded on a beach.

- [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/beached)

The term is often used for marine mammals, but applies to sailing vessels as well.

Answer (score -1):

There are a number of verbs that could be viably used in *winds _____ the boat ashore*: for example, **carried, bore, brought, drove, blew**.

The verb **carried** would be a good choice if the winds were gentle. **drove** would suggest a fairly strong wind.  **Blew** is neutral in terms of the force of the wind.